# GIMP determine guideline coordinate

Tags: gimp

I want to strictly determine position of guideline in GIMP.
Is there any method to determine coordinate of guideline in GIMP except mouse-hunting and checking ruler / mouse coordinate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ruler and the mouse coordinates display are somehow meant to show where things are:)

But you can get ofn-list-guides [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/). It adds `Image>Guides>List guides` in the menus and will list the guide positions in an error dialog (or the error console if you use it).